# Parse code file

Tags: ruby, parsing, text

nd maybe there is some tool for this? I must extract entire blocks and subblocks like 'it'

Comment: It's not a good idea for the heart of your question to depend on a link. Should that link break in future, poof! I realize the code is quite extensive, but couldn't you present a simplified version in your question (which will survive foreover on SO)?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt *any parser* could help *to load code blocks into variables*. It would require `eval`, but even with `eval` it would be extremely hard to collect all the context etc.

It the target is `rspec` scenarios, I would go with monkeypatching [`rspec` core](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/acd503f6bb1870d26fedef2bdbc12982a1aff683/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb), prepending your own detectors like:

```
def before(*args, &block)
  MyCollector.collect_block(block)
  super(*args, &block)
end
```

Comment: I try to create fast insert of reusable feature specs code to ace editor with grouped describes blocks. But nestings are hard to handle. I dont think that your answer could help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it with

https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser
or 
https://github.com/whitequark/parser

and will receive an AST (Abstrax Syntax Tree) which you then can process further. Depending on the amount of details you need from the source, you could also use some Regexps or write your own parser...
Perhaps you can tell us a little more about your project (input, output, reasons)

Comment: Your answer is cool but I dont know how to handle nested things to save later. Entire concept is to load file, allow to insert user code into processed blocks and save them later into same file. I try to do something like wysiwyg but only with text insert.